# Dynamic sort top/bottom N values in excel 2019

Tags: excel

I'm currently using excel 365 but need to make a spreadsheet compatible with 2019.  I have a list of unique departments each with a specific volume of production.  I need to create a dynamic filter for the bottom 5 producers, along with a vlookup alternative to get the values so I can graph them.

In excel 365 it's as simple as
Departments: =FILTER(Metrics!$B$2:$B$41,Metrics!$AL$2:$AL$41<E22)
Values:      =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D25#,Metrics!$B$2:$AM$41,37,FALSE),"")

The table goes from A1:A41 with row 1 being the headers.

I've tried using MIN and SMALL but can't figure out how to get more than one value.  I'm open to but would prefer not to use VBA if I can help it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72747100/how-do-i-get-the-top-n-results-based-on-wildcard-criteria-via-a-formula-in-excel

Answer (score 0):

For a function using SMALL, you'll have to use it in an array.

To do that, type out your formula, then instead of hitting enter like usual, press 'ctrl + shift + enter' to tell Excel to use an array. This will put {} around your formula to indicate it worked properly. From there just drag your formula down your desired amount of columns and should be good to go.